# Do I need to explicitly initialize a std::unique_ptr in the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, unique-ptr

I have a class where one of the fields is `std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>`. This field is initially unset when the parent class object is constructed. Do I need to do:

```
field_(nullptr)
```

Or will this field get initialized automatically to the default value and will that be null?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don't need it. The [default constructor of `std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) will construct a `std::unique_ptr` owning nothing. The effect is same as initializing as `field_(nullptr)` explicitly.

> Constructs a `std::unique_ptr` that owns nothing. Value-initializes the stored pointer and the stored deleter.

Comment: nit: Typically we should say "No, you don't need it".